# Why should we use bulk triggers?

Tags: trigger

I am new to salesforce ,i need to know what is the need for going to bulk triggers?

what is bulk trigger??can anyone give detailed explanantion on this.

Comment: Manoj, have you tried searching 'salesforce bulkfiy triggers' yet? There are excellent explanations.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this best practice article: [Bulkify Your Code](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Bulkify_Your_Code)

> Code that has been bulkified (structured to handle processing of multiple records) will run properly in different contexts. In particular, if you import data, the trigger or method that ordinarily only receives a single record as input, will receive a hundred - to run correctly in this context (and others) it should be written to handle multiple records.

In other words, if you're ever bulk inserting/updating/deleting data (using the data loader or integrations), you'll want to use bulk triggers, otherwise you'll get errors.

Comment: Historically, triggers were not "bulk", e.g. each trigger ran on a single record at a time. This was *painfully* slow for integration users (e.g. Data Loader would run loads a magnitude or two slower), so they eventually made bulk triggers optional, then mandatory, as a matter of being good multi-tenant architecture tenants.

Answer (score 2):

Apex runs on a multitenant achitecture.The resources are shared by many instances .Hence there is a concept of governor limits .If your code is not bulkified the governor limit exception will come with very few records .

For example consider you are not bulk inserting record in trigger and instead you have insert(DML operation) inside the for loop

```
for(Account acc:lstacc){//Bad practice need to be bulkified 

    insert acc;

}
```

If your lstacc which is list of Accounts contains 150 records, you will hit limit of no of DML operations allowed in your apex context.User will see an exception thrown saying governor limit is hit .

To avoid these governor limits its best practice to bulkify code .

Ex:

```
try{
    insert lstacc;//Bulk insert Accounts collected in list of Accounts named lstacc
}
```

Governor limit cheatsheet

https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score -1):

There is an issue with bulk approach, if one record gets error (trigger error or validation error) then whole lot gets rejected.

Comment: That isn't correct, if you use the database.update (database.insert etc.) you can specify the boolean parameter allornone which allows the trigger to process a partially successful batch.